# How can I insert JSON into a script tage in a zope chameleon template?

Tags: javascript, json, pyramid, zope, chameleon

I am building a pyramid/python app where my view callable for a certain template passes in a value called data. This variable is an array in the form of `[[[x1,y1,z1,],...],[[v1,v2,v3],...]]`

in my viewcallable I have

```
import json

jsdata = json.dumps(data)
```

I want to put it into a javascript script tag section of my template so:

```
<script>
data=${jsdata}
</script>
```

but i'm pretty sure that syntax is incorrect. How can I do this?

Edit: from this: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/templates.html it seems that Genshi style replacements are the way to go, which I take to mean that what I have above is correct. I am still unsure however, about whether this should be treated differently because it is going inside a javascript tag. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to insert a *JavaScript* array, not a Python list.

The easiest way to convert between Python and JavaScript formats is to use the `json` module. JSON is a JavaScript subset for data after all:

```py
import json

jsdata = (json.dumps(data)
            .replace(u'<', u'\\u003c')
            .replace(u'>', u'\\u003e')
            .replace(u'&', u'\\u0026')
            .replace(u"'", u'\\u0027'))
```

then pass `jsdata` to your template instead. The `str.replace()` calls ensure that the data remains HTML safe.

In the template, interpolate this without escaping:

```xml
<script>
var data = ${structure:jsdata};
</script>
```

Comment: ok so what would be the format to pass in jsdata? Would it just be data=${jsdata}?

Comment: By the way if your data could contain a string containing "</script>" or an HTML comment this might make you vulnerable to XSS attacks.  Basically any strings in the data should not be user-entered free-form text.

Comment: @DobesVandermeer: updated to neuter HTML, thanks for flagging this!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Chameleon, but "classical" Zope Page Templates did not allow to do anything inside `script` tags - if you don't see your variables interpolated it is likely that Chameleon behaves the same. The reason for this, as I understand, is to avoid exactly this type of code generation (you're generating JavaScript from Python via the template). Also, ZPT is an XML-based templating language and the content of `<script>` tags does not have to be a valid XML.

To work around the problem, you could do something like

```
jsdata = '<script type="text/javascript">var data = ' + json.dumps(data) + ';</script>'
```

and in your template insert the whole thing:

```
<tal:myscript replace="structure jsdata" />
```

Alternatively, you could do something like

```
<tal:lt replace="string:&lt;" />script>
   var data = <tal:script replace="structure jsdata" />;
<tal:lt replace="string:&lt;" />/script>
```

which would hide the `script` tags from Chameleon.

It would be a good practice to try to keep the amount of generated JavaScript in your pages as minimal as possible.

Comment: In classical ZPT I usually use a `tal:content="string:var data=$jsdata;"` setup to generate `<script>` tag contents; Chameleon supports Genshi-style interpolation too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Nice trick with tal:content! By "Genshi-style interpolation" do you mean that <script>data=${jsdata}</script> should work in Chameleon, while tal:replace inside a `script` tag won't work? I haven't used Chameleon that much.